# Diagnose the reason why write_file doesn't work in CodeIgniter

Tags: file, codeigniter

I have the below code.
In my base directory where the main CodeIgniter PHP index file is, I have a directory pagemodules with permission 666.
What I want to do is write in it a file in the following filename format: `.main.control.function.var.something.mod`

To dynamically create files in this folder I use the below code to check if the file exists, if not, create it with a single space in it.

The only problem is, I come up with a fail every time. I have tried moving the dir into every possible directory to see if it's a file path problem, but that didn't help.
The CodeIgniter wiki isn't much help either because it gives no pointers on how to diagnose errors from the file helper. And no error is thrown whatsoever...

How can I get CodeIgniter to throw an error I can do something with?

I could start working with `fopen`, but I prefer to use CodeIgniter because of ease of use.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$this->load->helper('file');
if($createfile!=null)
{
    $filepath = './pagemodules/'.str_replace('/','.',$data['page']->url).'.mod';
    $file = read_file($filepath);
    if($file === false)
    {
        $test = write_file($filepath,' ','w+'); 
        if($test)
        {
            echo "we have written $filepath";
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'fail '.$filepath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: set permissions to 777 on the folder, and try it again.

Comment: That only adds excecution rights, and I don't need those, just reading and writing, for which 666 is sufficient. 777 doesn't help.

Comment: Does switching it to 777 help, though? You should isolate assumptions and make sure that it is indeed a write permissions problem. What user/group is the server (the script) running as? What is the user/group of the directory/file?

Comment: I grew up with unix, 777 doesnt change a thing for my purposes. I will try the FCPATH option and get back to you.

Comment: @manix could you please post your suggestion into an answer so I can accept it? Your suggestion solved my problem. The 777 option was useless(who needs execution rights on a read write directory anyways)

Comment: @yep, looks thw aswer, but I don't know why is duplicated :s and I can't delete the old one  u.u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, just for debug purposes:

Replace `'./pagemodules/` with `'FCPATH.'pagemodules/` in order to get absolute path to pagemodules (if it is located at index.php codeigniter directory).

To avoid an invalid path, you can use...

```
get_filenames('path/to/pagemodules/')
```

...to get its files and corroborate if it is correct.This function return and array with file names into it.

Remember that you can use `FCPATH` constant to get the absolute path to Codeigniter installation.